# How does redux-saga recurse over yielded (arrays of) generators?

Tags: javascript, generator, redux-saga

I've seen a root saga using `redux-saga` that looks like:

```
export default function* root() {
  yield [
    watch_sagaOne(),
    watch_sagaTwo(),
  ];
}
```

Where each watcher was e.g.

```
const watch_sagaOne = function* () {
   yield takeEvery('action_key', saga_handler)
}
```

Note that contrary to the docs there is no `all` effect used here.

The code is working as if the `takeEvery()` call had been executed, with saga_handlers being called every time the action key was emitted.

In short I don't understand how. My understanding is simply that the `sagaMiddleware.run(root)` function used to execute the root saga simply iterates until the `root()` generator is finished. This would lead to the following sequence:

```
sagaMiddleware.run(root)
// root is called to generate the rootGenerator generator
// rootGenerator.next() is called by redux-saga
// both watch_sagaOne and watchSagaTwo are executed to produce generators
// This yields an array of [ watch_sagaOneGenerator, watch_sagaTwoGenerator ]
// rootGenerator.next() is called by redux-saga, and finishes
```

However it appears like `redux-saga` also steps down into the yielded array and executes the two generators as well... is this true?

Comment: `redux_saga` is certainly looking at the values that are yielded from the generator. Otherwise, why would they be yielded at all?

Comment: right... that certainly does make sense now that you say it...!

Comment: so returning an array of generator objects is essentially the same as `fork` or `all` except that it is blocking?

Comment: It's equivalent to `await Promise.all([…])`, yes. The generators in the array will be run concurrently.

Comment: very precise. thanks. nearly missed the `await` keyword there on the promise.